# Magento 2 - Search result not working properly on dropdown attribue

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-attribute, search, magento2.3.5-p2

I have a dropdown attribute **brand**
**Use in Search** is set to **"Yes"**
**Search Weight** is set to **10**, tried with 7 as well
In configuration **Search Engine** is set to **MySql**

There are more than 100 products are set to attribute value like **"abc"** Brand

But when I search for the word **abc** it only shows 29 products.

Indexing are up to date.
Cache is cleared

Please guide me fix the search on dropdown attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to
`Catalog > Products`

Search for those products which are assigned to the brand you're searching and ensure that all the products visibility are set to `Catalog, Search`.

If they are not on `Catalog, Search` e.g some of the products are set to `Catalog` only, than change their visibility and set it to `Catalog, Search`.

After changing the visibility don't forget to reindex your data
`php path/to/root/bin/magento indexer:reindex`

I hope you'd find this answer useful.

Comment: Let me check this one. Thanks

Comment: Silly mistake, but this was the issue that you have pointed. Thanks mate :)